# Amazon open search service software update

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

We have a new service software update R20220323 in AWS console.

Is there will be any issues, If we start the update manually?

Answer (score 0):

Service software updates in Amazon OpenSearch Service are applied to the domain whether you want/like it or not. If you apply them manually you will have access to new features soon. So better do it manually. And as to your question about facing issues, You won't have any as this is not version upgrade but just minor updates to the system.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/service-software.html).

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**

no, there will be no issue, when you update to this release

**long version:**

Since three years, I never faced any issue for software releases or upgrade from one version to another. The service will receive all messages. Kibana/Dashboard will also be available during the update/upgrade process.

The only issue you see is a yellow state for Kibana/Dashboard for a short period of time. Since there is a real blue/green deployment, we never faced that issue again.

The update (and upgrade) process will create new nodes, copy/move all content to the new nodes and after this, all requests will be switch to these new nodes and the old one will be stopped.

Like I said, no downtime... in our 24/7 environment, we have almost the same traffic. So, just do it and communicate to your users, that there can be some issues in connecting to Kibana/Dashboard.

The duration for updating depends on the size of your nodes.